# How to set a checkbox on Datagridview Header Column C#

Tags: c#, checkbox, datagridview

how I can add an checkbox on Gridview Header Columns with ability select all/deselect all?
when click any columns I want to change checkbox value and calculate new Value. It's work but not perfect.

```
     private void setCheckBoxDG()
        {
            DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn checkboxColumn = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
            checkboxColumn.Width = 30;
            checkboxColumn.DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
            DGDoc.Columns.Insert(0, checkboxColumn);

            Rectangle rect = DGDoc.GetCellDisplayRectangle(0, -1, true);

            rect.X = DGDoc.Size.Width - 28;
            rect.Y = rect.Y + 2;
            CheckBox checkboxHeader = new CheckBox();
            checkboxHeader.Name = "checkboxHeader";
            checkboxHeader.Size = new Size(18, 18);
            checkboxHeader.Location = rect.Location;
            checkboxHeader.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler (checkboxHeader_CheckedChanged);
            DGDoc.Controls.Add(checkboxHeader);
        }

and
```

for select all/deselect :

```
string strIDs = "";
Int64 intSumPrice = 0;
Int64 intSumTax = 0;
Int64 intSumPay = 0;
foreach (DataGridViewRow item in DGDoc.Rows)
{
    if (item.Cells[0].Value == null)
        item.Cells[0].Value = "True";
        if (bool.Parse(item.Cells[0].Value.ToString()))
        {
            item.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(241, 215, 215);
            strIDs += "," + item.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            intSumPrice += Int64.Parse(item.Cells[4].Value.ToString());
            intSumTax += Int64.Parse(item.Cells[5].Value.ToString());
            intSumPay += Int64.Parse(item.Cells[6].Value.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            item.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Empty;
        }
    }
    DGDoc.EndEdit();

    txtSumPrice.Text = intSumPrice.ToString();   
    txtSumTax.Text = intSumTax.ToString();
    txtSumPay.Text = intSumPay.ToString();
    DGDoc.Refresh();
}
```

do you know another method to help me?

Comment: have you look at or Googled how to use / create `ItemTemplates`

Comment: _It's work but not perfect_ Do not let us guess just what is working and not working!! Write it in your question! Also it sounds as if you want to triiger an action, so use a `Button`, not a `CheckBox`!

Comment: What does `checkboxHeader_CheckedChanged` do? Where is your *select all/deselect all* code called?